# Why the last PL/SQL statement fails using dbms_assert.enquote_literal?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The firs and second "put_line" statements in the below PL/SQL block will succeed but the last one fails. Why? Could it be a bug?

```
declare
  x varchar2(100);
begin
  x := 'Test'''; 
  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', ''''''))); 

  x := 'Te''st';
  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', '''''')));  

  x := '''Test';
  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', ''''''))); 
end;
/
```

The error is:

```
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 317
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 381
ORA-06512: at line 11
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any idea?

Comment: As it seems it has something to do with the first character in the variable. It throws if the first character is a `'`

Comment: Take a look at the source of dbms_assert.

Comment: Feels like buggy behavior.

Comment: Not buggy: from docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABHBBFH "Verify that all single quotes ***except leading and trailing characters*** are paired with adjacent single quotes."

Comment: why `dbms_assert.enquote_literal(q'{''Test}')` fails but `dbms_assert.enquote_literal(q'{Test''}')` not?

Comment: @PavelGatnar, that's not possible. PL/SQL code is wrapped.

Comment: @wernfried copy the source, beautify it and rename the package name. Then call the copy instead of the original and find the error point in the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Can not tell you that why this is happening, but you can try as below to handle this:

```
    set serveroutput on;
declare
  x varchar2(100);
begin
  x := 'Test'''; 
  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', '''''')), ''' ', '''')); 

  x := 'Te''st';
  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', '''''')), ''' ', ''''));  

  x := '''Test';

  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' 
  || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', ' ''''')), ''' ', '''')
  ); 
end;
/

x is: Test', enquoted x is: 'Test'''
x is: Te'st, enquoted x is: 'Te''st'
x is:  'Test, enquoted x is: '''Test'
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: OR you can try the following:  x := '''Test';

  dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' 
  || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', ' ''''')), ''' ', '''')
  );

Comment: still getting the same error , after using your code in answer and using x:='''Test';

Comment: I just edited the answer again, run that plsql block again and then check, I am not getting any error here.

Comment: The solution fails for x := 'Te'' st'; However, I liked the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is mentioned on 
https://avoidsqlinjection.wordpress.com/category/5-filtering-input-with-dbms_assert/ 
that  `When using ENQUOTE_LITERAL, remember to escape single quotes in the input.` but not explained very well.

On oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65379

```
 Usage Notes    
        Verify that all single quotes except leading and trailing characters are paired with adjacent single quotes.    
        No additional quotes are added if the name was already in quotes.
```

This question is good example that ENQUOTE_LITERAL will not qoute strings which are already quoted.But whatever mentioned above only limits us for ENQUOTE_LITERAL.So what is solution for this. As @Vinish Kapoor does a trick in his answer that you can see. So in case of limitations we can convert string into some other pattern and replace it back to normal. you can use below also

```
 dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', '#')), '#', ''''));
```

or this one

```
 dbms_output.put_line('x is: ' || x || ', enquoted x is: ' || replace(dbms_assert.enquote_literal(replace(x, '''', '~')), '~', ''''));
```

beacuse leading and trailing single qoutes are causing problem we can conver them into # or ~ and after enquote_literal has done its work we can replace them back to single qoutes.